# Google Vision mysterious crash log

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-vision

Viewing the logcat output of a production app and found this mysterious crash. I have no idea how to comprehend it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Barcode API is partially implemented in native code, and you managed to trip over a bug in that native code, which resulted in a crash. We will have a fix in a future release of the API.

Thanks for the log output!